# THROUGH the partly closed curtains Jake can be seen stepping out of his front door

Tags: word-choice

(We're in a house across the street from Jake's house, looking out the window.)

**Through** the partly closed curtains, Jake can be seen stepping out of his front door.

- Is 'through' idiomatic here even though you technically don't look through the curtains?

Comment: It's fine. We say that someone looked through the curtains. Whether partially drawn curtains or net curtains is not relevant. Idiomatically, **drawn** works better in your example than **closed** although both are correct.

Comment: When I was little we (north London) talked about opening and closing the curtains. When I heard people talking about "drawing the curtains" I was confused and dissatisfied: did they mean opening or closing?

Comment: @ColinFine In superior costume dramas, curtains are drawn. I suspect that in the soaps they are merely closed or opened but this suspicion is based purely on surmise. It might be one of those **fewer** or **less** preferences. I confess to being among the former.

Comment: Oh, I've no doubt the English class system was in there. I was (implicitly) taught to  look down on those neighbours who said /jɪə/ rather than /jɜ:/ for "year".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a correct use of through. You can also, for example

> look through the leaves of a tree
> walk through a crowd of people

If the substance is made up of several parts, to do something through it can be to do something through the gaps in it. The case of *looking* of *seeing through* is a very old one and somewhat special: OED sense A.I.1.b for 'through,' *prep*. and *adv*. gives

> With reference to the transmission of light, or the action of looking or seeing, from one side of an opening, gap, or transparent object to the other.